# Rating bar step size not working in lollipop. But works in marshmallow

Tags: android, ratingbar

I made a ratingBar but when setting the rating as 2.5, the ratingBar in lollipop is showing 3 full stars but in marshmallow, 2 full stars and a half star is shown. I want to get 2 and a half star in all devices.

The ratingBar style I'm using is

```
<style name="smallRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small">
    <item name="android:progressTint">@color/custom_red</item>
    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:secondaryProgressTint">@color/custom_red</item>
    <item name="android:numStars">5</item>
    <item name="android:stepSize">0.5</item>
</style>
```

And the ratingBar used is

```
<RatingBar android:id="@+id/comment_rating"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:isIndicator="true"
 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
 style="@style/smallRatingBar"
 android:stepSize="0.5"
 android:rating="2.5"></RatingBar>
```

And here are the screenshots(first image from lollipop and second from marshmallow)

[image: Rating shown in lollipop devices]
[image: Rating shown in marshmallow devices]

I want lollipop also have half stars. Please help.

[EDIT 1]
Java code:

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.comment_rating);
ratingBar.setRating(item.getRating()); //getRating returns float value
```

This is happening inside a listview adapter

Comment: add your java code too?

Comment: any progress in this issue?